After upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04 how to install EPSON PERFECTION 4490 PHOTO software?
Upgrade to 24.04.1 OK
The software v2.30.4 taken from site http://support.epson.net/linux/en/iscan.php?model=gt-x750&version=2.30.4 which however was operational on Ubuntu 22.04
the message is :
libgcc-s1
libglib2.0-0t64
libgtk2.0-0t64
libsane not found (libsane>=1.0.11-3)
I found libsane_1.2.1-1_amd64.deb on a forum and then installed Image Scan! for Linux (v2, unofficial
The message was : scanner not found
I installed libsane-common_1.2.1-7build4_all.deb
The message was again : scanner not found
How can I install the driver ?
